# Why does adding a simple CHECK constraint take so long on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, check-constraints

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on Amazon RDS

I'm adding a `CHECK` constraint on an already indexed column named **timestamp_** of a table called **event_click** that contains about 1 million rows.

```
ALTER TABLE event_click_2016_8
ADD CONSTRAINT click_2016_8_chk CHECK ( timestamp_ >= '2016-8-01' AND timestamp_ < '2016-9-01' );
```

The above takes **15 minutes** to complete. Why is it so slow? What specifically is holding up this operation? There is nothing else running on the DB and no locks being held by other processes.

```
r3.large instance (2 vCPU, 15 GiB RAM)
maintenance_work_mem = 256147
work_mem = 1024000
```

Comment: Checking a million rows shouldn't take 15 minutes. Maybe it was waiting for a lock on the table. The Postgres Wiki contains some statement where you can monitor locks: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: This is something that occurred to me and I ensure that there is nothing blocking this query (no lock waits).

Comment: It is reproducible?  I can add such a constraint to a larger table in under a second.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing it. Maybe amazon IO flakyness

Answer (score 3):

when creating the constraint, check `pg_lock`s for `granted  is false` or `pg_stat_activity` for `wait_event_type` and `wait_event` `where pid = <pid that adds the check>` (note that these two columns are new in 9.6 - in earlier versions you see only the fact that it is waiting).

Most probably your `ALTER TABLE` was waiting for other process to release a lock before it could acquire exclusive one.

Comment: this was not the case. I updated my question to reflect that

Comment: well you can try running `timestamp_ >= '2016-8-01' AND timestamp_ < '2016-9-01'` before creating constraint, if it takes 15 minutes thet is it IO?..